# pspice error when coupling inductors

Tags: transformer, simulation, pspice, coupling

I am trying to simulate a simple transformer circuit in pspice v9.2.

[image: transformer circuit]

The circuit is based on pspice documentation [here](https://www.pspice.com/resources/application-notes/using-inductor-coupling-symbols)
coupling settings:

[image: coupling configuration]

But running the simulation results in some errors:

```
ERROR --  device L_L12 is undefined
ERROR --  device L_L13 is undefined
ERROR -- Less than 2 connections at node N07611
ERROR -- Less than 2 connections at node N07553
ERROR -- Less than 2 connections at node N06903
ERROR -- Node N07611 is floating
ERROR -- Node N07553 is floating
```

How can I resolve these errors? I tried using other models for inductors, but it had no effect, and it seems that I'm doing something wrong in the coupling configurations.

Comment: Please ask a question.